# Why can't I break a block in survival mode when just being in creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I just went from survival mode to creative mode and switched back, only to find that I can't break or set ANY blocks! How can I fix this???!

Comment: Luckily I answered this before it was duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a chance you might have accidentaly switched the Adventure Mode, and not Survival, since in adventure you need to mine stuff with the specific tools. I suggest using `gamemode s` to switch to Survival mode. If that doesn't work, I suggest making a save, exiting out of your PC or console. Restart the game and reload that save.